# Any possible problems when migrating SharePoint 2007 databases from SQL 2005 to 2012

Tags: content-database, sql-server-2012, database-attach, database-server, sql-server-2008

Due to SQL Server 2005 EOL, we plan to migrate all SharePoint 2007 and 2010 content databases to SQL Server 2012 (or SQL 2008).

I wonder if it will be safe to migrate, and any possible points to be careful on the migration process.

Should we move all SP 2007 content to SP 2010 before attempting to migrate?

Comment: SP 2007 will reach EOL in two years as well.

Answer (score 1):

1st thing, i am sure Sharepoint 2007 not supported with SQL 2012 or above. You have to upgrade the SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2010.

Once upgrade to 2010 then you can upgrade the Database to latest version of the SQL. While you upgrading the Content DB on sql, I would recommend shut down the SharePoint to avoid any issue.

Comment: Yep, SharePoint 2007 on SQL Server 2012 is not supported.  Apparently the main issue involves the sp_dboption stored procedure being removed in the latest version, and dbo.trace_xe_action_map being moved to the sys schema (this guy claims to have installed SP2007 in SQL2012 after hacking these pieces back in: https://blog.sharepointrx.com/2013/12/22/installing-microsoft-office-sharepoint-server-2007-on-sql-server-2012/)